# Replace guava Fluent Iterables with Streams

Tags: java, generics, java-8, java-stream, guava

I have a method for a filter by type, it gets as input `Collection<?> collection` and `Class<T> tClass`. I want to replace `FluentIterable` by the `Stream`.

```
public static <T> List<T> filterByType(final Collection<?> filerCollection, final Class<T> classType) 
{
    return FluentIterable.from(filerCollection).filter(classType).toList();
}
```

I tried with this solution:

```
public static <T> List<T> typeFilter(final Collection<?> filter, final Class<T> classType) {
    return (List<T>) filter.stream()
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .map(Object.class::cast)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

how to do that without casting the return `Stream`?

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to check if your elements are even of type `T`. I.e. you have to filter those elements out first:

```
return filter.stream()
             .filter(classType::isInstance) // only keep elements of type T
             .map(classType::cast)          // safely cast from Object to T
             .collect(Collectors.toList()); // collect into a List<T>
```

`Class#isInstance()` also directly takes care of `null` values, so you don't have to use `filter(Object::nonNull)`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `classType::cast` because here you're using `Object.class::cast` which basically does *nothing*

```
public static <T> List<T> typeFilter(final Collection<?> filter, final Class<T> classType) {
    return filter.stream()
                 .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                 .map(classType::cast)
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

And to be even better, add a `filter(classType::isInstance)` to your method chaining

Answer (score 1):

Look carefully what [`FluentIterable::filter(Class<T>)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/FluentIterable.html#filter-java.lang.Class-) does and compare it with *maps* each item to the `classType` with casting. Your intention is to filter those items of `classType`.

Next, the `classType::cast` should be used instead of `Object.class::cast` since the desired class is already passed through `Class<T> classType` and might be used directly as a method reference. The `Object.class::cast` casts to a parent `Object` which every object inherits from.

Here is what you want:

```
public static <T> List<T> typeFilter(final Collection<?> filter, final Class<T> classType) {
    return filter.stream()
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .filter(item -> item.getClass().equals(classType))
        .map(classType::cast)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

<sub>Edit: As mentioned in another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56332397/3764965), the `filter(classType::isInstance)` might be used as well.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you can do (though it's probably a bit less efficient than doing it in two steps) is to define something like this:

```java
public static <T> Function<Object, Stream<T>> instancesOf(Class<T> c) {
  return o -> c.isInstance(o) ? Stream.of(c.cast(o)) : Stream.empty();
}
```

and then use it like this:

```java
return filter.stream()
    .flatMap(instancesOf(classType))
    .collect(toList());
```